# Looking for a suitable bibliography style file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

My university requires the following format for bibliographic entries:

> P.W. Anderson, “More is different” Science 177, 393-399 (1972);
>
> C.V. Negoita, Fuzzy Systems (Abacus Press. Tunbridge Wells, UK, 1980).
>
> K. Hirai, M. Hirose, Y. Haikawa and T. Takenaka, “The Development of Honda Humanoid Robot,” In: Proceedings of the IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (1998) pp. 1321-1326.

Can someone tell me which bibliography style to use to achieve the format shown above?

Comment: Welcome, looks like an author-title style.

Comment: I tried to use standard styles, but there are slight differences. I tried using natbib and custom-bib. Since I'm new, I can't find out how it is possible.

Comment: @ALIFARID — Your write-up is not entirely clear. You’ve set the `biblatex` tag, yet in a comment you mention that you use the `natbib` and `custom-bib` packages, which are both incompatible with the `biblatex` package. Please clarify. Please also indicate what you’ve tried to do with the `custom-bib` package. E.g., did you try to run the package’s `makebst` utility?

Comment: @Mico, Thanks for your clarification. I am using LaTEX and I tried to customize similar styles to my reference format. I tried to run makebst utility on WinEdt, but I couldn't get the outcome.

Comment: There are at least three important issues with your posting; taken together, these issues make it nearly impossible to run the `makebst` utility successfully. First, you don't mention what the citation style should be: authoryear, numeric, superscript-numeric, or something else? Second, you (or your university) provide no guidance as to how entries of type `@techreport`, `@misc`, `@unpublished` etc should be formatted. Third, your write-up contains a few inconsistencies. E.g., why is the first entry terminated by a semicolon whereas the other two are terminated with a period (aka "full stop")?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the OP has reported having located a bib style file that meets all of his/her requirements.

Answer (score 2):

After you settle with your university how entries of type `@techreport`, `@misc`, and `@unpublished` -- to name just a few important entry types -- should be formatted, I would urge you to run the `makebst` utility once more and create a custom bst file. The structured question-and-multiple-choice-answer format of the utility should let you achieve virtually all of your university's formatting requirements.

There is one important exception to the claim in the preceding sentence, though: The requirement to place an author's initials *before* the surname, *while not allowing whitespace between the initials*. Here's a proposed fix. First, while running the `makebst` utility, you will get to the following screen:

[image]

Be sure to choose the third option, i.e., to type `i` in order to select "(i) Initials and surname (J. F. Smith)".

Second, when you're done with running the utility and have created the new bst file, open that file in a text editor and search for the BibTeX function called `format.names`. In that function, find the following line:

```
      "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
```

Change this line to

```
      "{f{.}.}{ vv}{ ll}{, jj}"
```

With this change in place, whitespace between the abbreviated first names will be suppressed. E.g., if "Constantin Virgil Negoita" is the full name of one of the authors, it will get typeset as "C.V. Negoita" -- exactly what your university requires.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: I found the exact reference style in a Cambridge journal: 
 https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/FD592CA3B8D8D61883CA918EA2EE2D3A/S0263574719000067a.pdf/design_and_evaluation_of_a_soft_assistive_lower_limb_exoskeleton.pdf

Comment: I tried your mentioned approach, but after adding a reference style, it is not working and there are 99 warnings.

Comment: Is there easier way? I am totally confused.

Comment: @ALIFARID - I'm afraid I don't understand what you're looking for. Didn't you report ca 12 minutes ago that you found the exact bst file? So you no longer need an answer to your query. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment,  I just give a link for the PDF file that contains the style, not the bst file. Since I thought it is a very complicated style for a newbie like me.

Comment: @ALIFARID - Since the journal appears to be a part of the Cambridge University Press collection of journals, you may want to search the CUP webpages if they provide a link to a suitable bib style file.

Comment: @ALIFARID - I'm afraid that comments such as "it is not working" are so unspecific as to be unusable. What exactly did you do? Did you run the `makebst` utility? If so, did you then open the bst file in a text editor, locate the `format.names` function, and locate the string `"{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"` inside that function? Please be specific.